# NSFetchResultsController too slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using `NSFetchResultsController` to receive items from database (there are 80.000 items).

This is my predicate: `@"(desc CONTAINS[cd] %@)", [any text]`

And for `NSFetchRequest` I set next properties:

```
request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entityDescription propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"icd"]];
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
[request setFetchBatchSize:100];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"icd" ascending:YES]]];
```

The idea behind this is that I want a live search (every character user writes in a textfield, the `NSFetchResultsController` should fetch into database again.

The problem is next: on iPad Mini, every fetch duration is between 2-3 seconds, which is very very much. I remember that I did same thing now 1 years ago, and worked faster.

Can you please give me some advice? I really don't know how to improve query.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your predicate.  It causes a scan of every record to find which ones contain the desired search text.  Furthermore, using [cd] makes it even slower.

This exact problem is addressed in the [2013 WWDC presentation on Core Data Performance](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-211/).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know that the predicate is the problem, because i use CONTAINS[cd]. Do you have a solution for this, for optimizations?

Comment: @ChirilaVasile - Yes.  As I said in the answer, your exact problem is addressed in the 2013 WWDC presentation on Core Data Performance.  Click on that link and watch the video.

Comment: Also consider that only your first search should be against the database.  Each character pressed after the first should be against the existing array that is in memory, not back out to disk again.  That will dramatically help in search performance after the first key is pressed.